# Can't resolve symbols

Tags: libgdx

I am making a touch button but libGDX can't recognize 'LevelChooser' 'Kombat' 'introscreen' 'wait' 'lowerflag' 'curLevel'

```
public class TouchButton extends TextButton {
    LevelChooser lc;
    public TouchButton(String text, TextButtonStyle skin,Kombat game) {
        super(text, skin);
        this.lc=game.introScreen.lc;
    }
    @Override
    public void act(float delta){
        wait+=delta;
        if(lc.lowerFlag && lc.curLevel>0 && wait>delta*8) {
            lc.curLevel--;
            lc.level.setText("" + lc.curLevel);
            wait=0f;
        }
    }
}

}
```

This is in my create method:

```
    less.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                            int pointer, int button) {
            boolean touchdown = true;


        }

        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                                 int pointer, int button) {
            boolean touchdown = false;

            return true;
        }
```

And I also got this:

```
less = new TouchButton("lower", style,game);
```

Comment: What are `LevelChooser` and `Kombat`? Are these classes you created? If so, what packages are they in? And what package is `TouchButton` in? You probably need the correct import statements to get things all hooked together. I suggest you do some research on packages and import statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means that your class has no access to these fields/variables. This could be because of several things.

- You made a typo
- The field/variable does not exists.
- You made the field private/protected and try to access it from outside
- You did not specify the visibility (private/public) which means that it is only visible for classes in the same package.

I suggest you make `LevelChooser` `curLevel` public and see if it has access.

If you want to properly program you then make this variable private again and grand access to a getter and/or a setter if you want to change it.

```
private int currentLevel;
public getCurrentLevel() { 
  return currentLevel; 
}
public setCurrentLevel(int currentLevel) { 
  this.currentLevel = currentLevel;
}
```

Most IDE's have the ability to generate the getters/setters semi automaticaly. In Android Studio I just press `ALT+INS` and select either `create getter`, `create setter` or `create getter/setter` and then select the field I want to create these for. So this costs no additional time and whenever you decide you want to increment currentLevel AND change the screen you can do that by simply altering the setter.

```
public setCurrentLevel(int currentLevel) { 
  this.currentLevel = currentLevel;
  ((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener).setScreen(new LevelScreen(currentLvel));
}
```

I also suggest you name your variables properly. `curLevel` becomes `currentLevel` and `lc` becomes `LevelChooser`. This will save you and everything you ask help big time. It only costs you a second if you use a proper IDE, android studio even suggests this naming so it would actually save you time in that IDE.